# Is this one database query or two? Is where allowed after get() in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is where allowed after get() in Laravel eloquent?
Is this one database query or two?

> Student::where('rank_id',1)->get()->where('id',29152);

Answer (score 1):

This part  `Student::where('rank_id',1)->get()` will perform a query into the database and the `->where('id',29152);` will filter the collection already retrieved without make another query.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-where

Comment: One should add that it is preferred to use `where()` on the query builder than on collections where possible as performance of database queries is normally a lot better. What's best depends on the exact use case and other details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed as Student::where('rank_id',1)->get() returns collection and you can chain results of collection using where.

Refer to Illuminate>Support>Collection.php for details of functions that can be used on a collection

Comment: It will be one query as your chaining on collection the part before where('id',29152); gets you database results.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel connects to different databases uses [`connections`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections). So until you are not specifying any connection :

1. By explicitly calling `DB::connection()`
2. Or by specifying `protected $connection= 'second_db_connection';` in any of your eloquent models

You are basically dealing with just one default connection which means one database.

In your query `Student::where('rank_id',1)->get()->where('id',29152)`, it should be :

```
Student::where('rank_id',1)->where('id',29152)->get();
```

It's the syntax used by query builder, which is in the format. `->get()` is used to apply the selections and filters you have applied on a query. So where should be before `get()`.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) for more help.